# Sorting out with highest values first

Tags: swift

```
for (index, item) in users.enumerated(){
//countUserIds[item.name] = [Float(item.id),avgs[index]]
print("Name:",item.name,"ID:",item.id,"Score:",avgs[index])
}
```

[image: Output]

Im trying to sort my output by having the highest averages listed first, but if I sort my array it will not be linked to the right name and ID. How can I sort the averages and display the users with the highest average first?

Comment: Why averages value is not a variable of `item` class? If so you can easily sort it.

Comment: the average are calculated based on data within a users.json file so the averages aren't linked to that struct

Comment: Not sure why that stopping you from adding that value to the struct, either way you can also create a dictionary [Int: User] then sort that.

Comment: How can I add individuals averages to the existing struct and make sure that it links with the right user? I tried using a dictionary which does work but the format isn't proper. I might just go with the dictionary if I can't get the format right tbh

Comment: You need to add a better explanation of your data model, you say that the average values aren’t linked to the struct objects so it’s a mystery how you want to sort them together as one unit

Comment: I ended up just creating a dictionary with the name of the user as the key and the value as the average and sorted them in descending order. But I was wondering if it's possible to have two keys for the dictionary? EX: [Keys(ID, Name) Value(Avg)] something like this. I don't thinks its possible to have two keys with different types but I thought I'd ask